WGS84 elevation from ALOS 30m DSM tif's using rasterio
I am new to GIS processing.
I am trying to compute WGS84 elevation for given latitude and longitude using the JAXA ALOS 30m DSM. I use rasterio and code from a minimal example I found that looks like the following:
with rasterio.open(dsm_tile_path) as tile:
    coord = tile.index(lon, lat)
    elevation = tile.read(
        indexes=1,
        window=rasterio.windows.Window(coord[1], coord[0], 1, 1),
        resampling=Resampling.nearest,
        out_dtype=float
    )[0][0]

This code seems to produce sensible-looking elevations, when compared to GSM datapoints near my location. Do you see any red flags in it?
More importantly, what is the reference for the elevations thus computed? The ALOS documentation says this in regard to the content of the DSM tif images:
Elevation (in meter) converted from the ellipsoidal height based
on ITRF97 and GRS80, using EGM96 geoid model.
Signed 16bit (LSB) raster data, GeoTIFF format.
Equirectangular projection, Spacing: 1 arcsec. (approx. 30 m)
Average and median values are adopted in resampling the
0.15 arcsec. resolution DSM into 1 arcsec. resolution.
Value “-9999” are stored in void pixels

Does the above mean that the elevation returned by my call to tile.read above is height with respect to the EGM96 geoid? Do I just need to add the EGM96 geoid height at the same (lat, lon) to get the WGS84 elevation?

I'd use tile.sample instead of getting the index and then constructing and reading a window.  E.g. for val in tile.sample([(lon1, lat1), (lon2, lat2), etc...]):    print(val)
